# Autre question concernant l'emploi de « nègre » en français

Tags: usage

La question sur l'emploie du mot en tant que « prête plume » est une question résolue en France, du moins du point de vue « formalités ». Cependant on a l'impression que les choses ont encore une fois été faites à moitié ; il reste dans le langage un terme consacré, je veux parler du terme « art nègre » et il y en a d'autres, pour ne citer que le mot « négritude ». Voit-on une différence dans le ton de ces emplois particuliers ? On est bien à mal de trouver un substitut pour « art nègre », pourtant il semble que le tour de celui-ci sous la guillotine du politiquement correct ne puisse être loin. Est-ce que quelqu'un saurait pourquoi ces termes subsistent ? Est-ce que quelqu'un saurait pourquoi, donnée l'impulsion qui a aboutit à la loi de 2017 concernant le remplacement du mot « nègre » par un terme sans connotations racistes,  a fait défaut cet esprit de continuation qui aurait dû s'imposer  pour effectuer dans la langue une véritable tâche de nettoyage linguistique ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il existe bien une expression moins connotée et plus courante qu'*art nègre*: *art africain traditionnel*, voire *art africain* tout court. *Art nègre* est une expression vieillie, et de nos jours, il me semble qu'elle n'est plus utilisée dans les musées ou en histoire de l'art.

*Négritude* n'a pas de connotation négative, bien au contraire, c'est un terme qui désigne de manière positive le sentiment d'appartenance à un espace culturel commun. Vu que c'est un terme créé et utilisé par des auteurs africains, il ne me parait pas être suspecté de la même connotation colonialiste ou raciste.

Comment: Les exemples au mot « négritude » dans le TLFi confirment bien vos dires, mais  ne serait-on  toujours pas trop complaisant dans cette attitude qui est celle de s'en remettre à l'esprit pratique de quelques  noirs qui peut être dans un soucis de recouvrir les idées désagréables du passé leur offrent une apologie inconsciente; la racine reste; de plus, par exemple « nègre » est toujours « homme de race noire » et on peut dire en même temps « Il l'a traité comme un nègre.». Je reste sceptique quant à votre assurance que ce soit le dernier mot.

Comment: "Quelques noirs"... Léopold Senghor et Aimé Césaire...

Comment: Un article intéressant sur le sujet, et sur l'origine du mot *négritude*, qui voulait prendre précisémement le contre-pied de la connotation raciste de "nègre": https://www.itineraireshumanistes.org/?p=838

Comment: Le terme « art africain » ne semble finalement pas une bonne solution : il résout un problème pour en introduire un autre; on doit inclure tout le Maghreb et l'Afrique du Sud dans cette dénomination; par « art nègre » il n'a jamais été question d'autre chose que de l'art exclusivement associé à la race noire en tant que son origine et son inspiration.

Comment: Le terme « art africain » ne semble finalement pas une bonne solution : il résout un problème pour en introduire un autre; on doit inclure tout le Maghreb et l'Afrique du Sud dans cette dénomination; par « art nègre » il n'a jamais été question d'autre chose que de l'art exclusivement associé à la race noire en tant que son origine et son inspiration. (Il y a d'autres questions, cependant, comme celle que suscite le jazz, par exemple.)

Comment: Je suis d'accord, le terme "art africain" est moins précis que "art nègre"; mais si vous regardez dans les listes des collections de musées, c'est cependant (peut-être faute de mieux) celui que l'on y trouvera, et non plus "art nègre".  On pourrait dire "art d'Afrique noire" voire "art d'Afrique sub-saharienne" ?

Comment: L'un de ces choix aurait été une bien meilleure idée, il me semble; je pensais moi-même à  « art noir primitif ».

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que la tendance récente est d'essayer de supprimer les connotations racistes du mot « nègre », et ça a un relatif succès. Le problème c'est que ça entre en conflit avec l'emploi de « nègre » pour désigner un esclave en dehors de tout contexte historique, comme le faisait l'expression mentionnée de « nègre » littéraire. Il y a en fait un conflit entre essayer de faire perdre la racine étymologique, « noir », de ce terme d'un côté (ce qui est très probablement la mauvaise approche) et lui faire perdre toute synonymie directe, non historique, avec « esclave » de l'autre (ce qui semble pouvoir fonctionner).

Comment: Je crois plutôt que l'emploi de « nègre » n'insiste pas sur une notion tout à fait exacte d'esclavage dans ce cas (on parle de gages) et que dans tous les cas, dans l'usage moderne de « nègre » ne doive pas être lu en un degré important  la notion d'esclavage mais celle de race méprisable,  inférieure.

Comment: La notion retenue c'est de faire faire le travail à quelqu'un d'autre sans que cette personne soit reconnue pour cela. Pour le second point, il faut faire attention à ne pas mélanger les connotations que le mot a en français avec celles qu'il a dans d'autres langues (en particulier l'anglais). Dans mon expérience, en français c'est moins le mot lui-même qui est raciste que le sens qui peut lui être conféré.